# Conda install package (Luigi) in base environment

Tags: conda, anaconda3, luigi

So I am new to this and I need to install Luigi by Spotify, task scheduler. I am running :

```
conda install luigi
```

It is progressing and then getting stuck at 'Solving Environment'.
We don't use a virtual environment to run our application. Is there no way to install Luigi without a virtual environment, i.e directly in the base environment ? Thanks.